# Reduce and join on window

Tags: apache-flink

I need to join two keyed streams on a window. But I need to first reduce the two streams and then apply the join on the aggregate all within the same window.

I have spent some time looking at Flink APIs and I find that such an apply function exists in a WindowedStream

public  SingleOutputStreamOperator apply(ReduceFunction reduceFunction, WindowFunction function)

But I am not able to find a similar function in a JoinedStream.
Question: 
   Would this be a useful enhancement to Flink.
   Is there a workaround that I can use for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using processing-time semantics, you can just apply the window-aggregation to each input stream independently and feed the result into the join (of course, both aggregates and the join must use the same window definition).

Something like this:

```java
WindowAssigner w = ...
reducedStream1 = stream1.keyBy(...).window(w).apply(...);
reducedStream2 = stream2.keyBy(...).window(w).apply(...);
reducedStream1.join(reducedStream2)
              .where(...).equalTo(...)
              .window(w).apply(...);
```

For processing-time, you would need to write you own custom operator using:

```java
stream1.coGroup(stream2)
       .where(...).equalTo(...)
       .window(...).apply(CoGroupFnction);
```

Comment: I am using event time and I ended up implementing it using coGroup just like what you have suggested. Thanks.